# Crash when using Location.getSpeed

Tags: java, android, gps, location

It seems like everytime it tries to display the speed, it crashes, and as long it dosent have a location and needs to print out "--" it's fine!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);

    this.onLocationChanged(null);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if(location == null){textView.setText("--");}
else{textView.setText((int)location.getSpeed());}
}
}
```

Comment: In what way does it crash? What stack trace is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf((int)location.getSpeed()));
```

Because when you passing an int to TextView.SetText, it expect a resource id